# How to correctly pass Arraylist to background service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, service

I want to pass the arraylist of all the phonenumbers created into the background service so that I can message them all at once when a shake gesture is triggered.

This is the `MainActivity` snippet where I use the `intent.putExtra()` method to pass my arraylist into the service.

```
SensorService sensorService = new SensorService();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, sensorService.getClass());
            if(!isMyServiceRunning(sensorService.getClass())){
                startService(intent);
                intent.putExtra("ContactNumberList", Contact_Number);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Starting Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

and  this is the snippet for assigning the passed arraylist. in the `SensorService`

```
       DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(SensorService.this);
       ArrayList<String> Contact_id, Contact_Name, Contact_Number;
       ArrayList<String> phonenumber = new ArrayList<String>();
       phonenumber = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ContactNumberList");
```

I get the compiler error `Cannot resolve method 'getIntent()'`

I wanted to know if there is a better way to pass the created arraylist from the `MainActivity` to my background service ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `(ArrayList<String>)` type cast. It should give you the option to import `getIntent` after that. If you need to type cast it, you can do it after you have the value.

Comment: sorry If am misunderstanding your solution but even when I remove the cast such that it looks like `ArrayList<String> numbersList = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");` it still does not give an option to import getIntent and still gives the cannot resolve error.

Comment: All good. So you removed `(ArrayList<String>)` on the following line? 
`phonenumber = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ContactNumberList");`

Comment: It should look like this: `phonenumber = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ContactNumberList");`

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. call "intent.putExtra(...)" BEFORE use that intent on startService()
2. implement "onStartCommand(Intent intent...) { ... } in your Service and use "intent" parameter (this method is called from MainThread/UiThread)